# Can lambda pull in npm dependencies on the fly

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to build potentially hundreds of different node projects using lambda.

Is it possible for lambda to perform a npm install to download all the node modules or do I have to first send lambda all my dependencies with my code? i.e. the node_modules folder.

Comment: If you are doing hundreds, you might want to consider something like serverless or Claudia - will save a lot of time and they pack and deploy code to Lambda so you don't have to and yes, if you choose to not use these, you have to include dependencies before you upload.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a feature that Lambda offers. The documention for Lambda says that you need to pack everything in your Lambda function into the zip-file you later upload. That means all source code, including node_modules.

However, to have Node.JS fetch code and run it during runtime would be possible. You can make it work using a HTTP client (`request`, `axios`, `http`) to pull the code and then combine that with `require` to load it into the process.